# Break li element content

Tags: css

I want to display `li` elements in `ul` element as one inline text, and on smaller screens I want the last li element to be displayed in the next line.

This is my example :

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    word-break: break-word;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    list-style: none;
}

li:not(:last-child)::after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #9aa6c4;
  margin: 0 12px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Word</li>
  <li>26-OCT-20</li>
  <li>LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG TEEEEEEEEEEEEEEXT</li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

So here on smaller screen I want all the `li` elements except the last one to act line one line, so the text will break and not the `li` elements, but the last `li` element will always break to the next line if there is no space left.

For example I want this:

[image]

Instead of this :

[image]

How can I solve this (without using media queries)?

Comment: This is precisely the use case media queries were created to handle. Why not use them?

Comment: @HereticMonkey because the length of the li content can be changed, so which breakpoint should be used?

Comment: But it's about the width of the container, not the width of the `li`, right? So the breakpoint at which you want "all the li elements except the last one to act line one line". Unless you want long lines to always break like shown, irrespective of the width of the container, in which case, the "smaller screens" is just a red herring, a coincidence that happens to be where you're seeing the symptom, not a defining characteristic of when you want the CSS to apply...

Comment: @HereticMonkey Exactly, I want the other li elements except the last one to act like one single line, and it will break depending on the container, but the content of the last element will never break, so this li element will always go to the next line if there is no enough space left.

Comment: Well, technically the "last element" is the link. Is it always the third list item?

Comment: Can't you just make the last element display block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gets you where you want to go, I think. I just left the `ul` as its default `display: block` and changed the `li` to `display: inline`. I also altered the break properties a bit.

Note that if you click Run code snippet, a "Full page" link shows up in the upper-right corner; click that and you can use developer tools to mimic small screens pretty well.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  overflow-wrap: anywhere;
  word-break: break-all;
}

li:not(:last-child)::after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #9aa6c4;
  margin: 0 12px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Word</li>
  <li>26-OCT-20</li>
  <li>LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG TEEEEEEEEEEEEEEXT</li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```